# Angular: Fire "change" event of radio button when binding to "checked" attribute

Tags: html, angular, binding, angular6

I have the following radio button:

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="productSel" id="product1" 
                (change)="handleChangedEvent(retailProduct)"
                [checked]="retailProduct.id === currentRetailProduct.ReplacementRetailProductId">
```

What I would like to accomplish, seems rather simple, but I cannot get it to work.

As you can see, I have a condition on my `[checked]` attribute. When this condition evaulates to true, I would like my `(change)` event to fire, but it does not.  It only fires when I select the radio button on the page manually.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<input type="radio" class="form-control" name="productSel" id="product1" 
(change)="radio.checked && handleChangedEvent(retailProduct)"
[checked]="retailProduct.id === currentRetailProduct.ReplacementRetailProductId">
```

Comment: Having a quick look at this, and does not seem to be what I want.  This will not call the event "handleChangedEvent(retailProduct)" when the user selects other radio buttons.

Comment: Do you want it when checkbox is checked?

Comment: You can `and` your condition and it will work as you want. Please let me know if its work for you